# Не работает плагин ACF на странице

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Подключил плагин ACF, и создал свою новую страницу send.php, при переходе по ссылке на страницу в разделе Страницы всё корректно добавляется, но по ссылке в форме не работает, как можно исправить проблему? Спасибо

Вот ссылка по которой перехожу:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/send.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
```

Внутри файла подключаю

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Думаю, что дал ответ в комментарии на предыдущий вопрос.

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: @Max Не выводит ничего

Comment: Вам же в прошлом ответе сказали, что форму нужно отправить аяксом и при удачной отправке сделать редирект

Comment: @Max мне такой вариант не подходит, я писал в чате. Мне KAGGDesign подсказал, что нужно получить id поста, я заменил $posts = get_field('new_post'); на $posts = get_field('160'); и ничего не изменилось, что я сделал не правильно, спасибо

Comment: Должно быть как-то так: get_field('field_name', 160);

Comment: @Max спасибо, это помогло, я просто не сразу понял что мне написал KAGGDesign, спасибо большое

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У вас в файле не определен текущий пост. Вы можете использовать `setup_postdata( 10 );` или при получении указывать post_id вторым параметром: `get_field( 'field_name', 10 )`